# Drag and Drop Replace Images

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

```js
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) 
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 if (ev.target.hasChildNodes()) {
  alert("This already contains a image");
 }
 else
 {
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>PUZZLE</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="puzzletest.css">
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="puzzletest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


   <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="drag2" src="puzzle12.jpeg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
   </div>

  <img id="drag1" src="puzzle01.jpeg" draggable="true"ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

  
</body>

</html>
```

Current HTML

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <img id="drag2" src="puzzle12.jpeg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</div>

<img id="drag1" src="puzzle01.jpeg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
```

How can I check if the division already contains an image and if it does it should replace the image with the draggable image or print an alert?

As you can see if I put one Image to the other one disappears try it out

Comment: Try with "dropzone.js"

Comment: Can you create a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? Also, any errors in the `console`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with`ev.target.hasChildNodes()` - the `target` is the `#drag2` but you need the `div`, so use `currentTarget` instead.

```js
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) 
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (ev.currentTarget.hasChildNodes()) {
    alert("This already contains a image");
  }
  else
  {
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>PUZZLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="puzzletest.css">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="puzzletest.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img id="drag2" src="puzzle12.jpeg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
    </div>

    <img id="drag1" src="puzzle01.jpeg" draggable="true"ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">


  </body>

</html>
```